# How to use Pivot table for calculating in this scenario?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to get the below result from the given data.

Report

```
-------------------------------------------------
 ID    |    Name          |    Status
-------------------------------------------------
  1    |     A            |    Inprogress
  2    |     A            |    Inprogress
  3    |     A            |    Complete
```

I need to calculate the result like

```
---------------------------------------------
Name    |   Total  | Complete  |  Remaining
---------------------------------------------
   A    |    3     |   1       |    2
```

SQL:

```
Select 
    [Inprogress], [Complete], [Printed] 
from  
    (select 
         specimenID, count([RStatus]) 
     from tbl_LabReport 
     group by specimenID) as sourcetable   
Pivot 
    (Count(specimenID) for [RStatus] in ( [Inprogress],[Complete],[Printed] ))  as ptv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `PIVOT` operator. Try to use `subquery` or `CROSS APPLY` operator to solve your task

```
;WITH test_data AS(
    SELECT 1 AS id, 'A' AS NAME, 'Inprogress' AS [status]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'A', 'Inprogress'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'A', 'Complete'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 'B', 'Complete'
)

SELECT DISTINCT
       name,
       T3.*
FROM test_data AS T
CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN T2.status = 'Complete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS complete, 
                    SUM(CASE WHEN T2.status = 'Inprogress' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS remaining 
             FROM test_data AS T2
             WHERE T2.name = T.name) AS T3
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few approaches you could take.  This example uses [CASE expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181765.aspx).  If you are not familiar with the concept a CASE allows you to conditional return a selected value.  I've converted your sample data into table variable:

**Sample Data**

```
/* Creating sample data inside a table variable makes it
 * easy to share.
 */
DECLARE @Sample TABLE
    (
        ID            INT,
        Name        VARCHAR(50),
        [Status]    VARCHAR(50)
    )
;

/* Sample values taken from OP.
 */
INSERT INTO    @Sample
    (
        ID,
        Name,
        [Status]
    )
VALUES
    (1, 'A', 'Inprogress'),
    (2, 'A', 'Inprogress'),
    (3, 'A', 'Complete')
;
```

The CASE returns a 1 for the required *Status* and a 0 for everything else.  Summing the result provides sub totals.

```
/* Using CASE to return conditional sub totals.
 */
SELECT
    Name,
    COUNT([Status])                                                AS Total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] = 'Complete'    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)        AS Complete,
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] = 'Inprogress'    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)    AS Remaining
FROM
    @Sample
GROUP BY
    Name
;
```